# Unit Testing - Raising static event to test proper event handler assignment

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, static

I have a class with a static event.

```
public class EventOrigin {
    public static event handler eventOccurred;
    public delegate void handler(string arg1, string arg2);
}
```

I have a different class which hooks into these events.  I would like to test that these events are properly hooked into.

```
public static class ConsumesEvent {
    public static register(){
        EventOrigin.eventOccurred += eventOrigin_eventOccurredHandler;
    }

    public static void eventOrigin_eventOccurredHandler(string arg1, string arg2){
        //some stuff happens here
    }
}
```

What I need to test is that specifically when `EventOrigin.eventOccurred` is fired after `ConsumesEvent.register()` that the appropriate handler is being fired.  That seems to mean I must raise the `EventOrigin.eventOccurred` event in my test.

I'm guessing that perhaps reflection could be used.  Is there a particular pattern which may make this easier and obviate the need for reflection in my unit tests?

Comment: Why would you need reflection? Is there no method that raises this event?

Comment: Exactly.  At least there's none that are safe to call in a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by deciding that I don't need to raise the event myself.  Instead I can have a private method to raise the event and then use `PrivateType` to invoke that method.

```
public class EventOrigin {
    public static event handler eventOccurred;
    public delegate void handler(string arg1, string arg2);

    #region testability seams

    private static raiseEventOccurred(string arg1, string arg2) {
        if(eventOccurred != null)
            eventOccurred(arg1, arg2);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Which is later consumed in a test like so:

```
private void whenEventRaised_someStuffHappens(){
    PrivateType eventOriginType = new PrivateType(typeof(EventOrigin));
    eventOriginType.InvokeStatic("raiseEventOccurred", "arg1", "arg2");

    Assert.IsTrue(overthinkingTheProblemIsDangerous);
}
```

A nice side effect is the code around raising the event gets the null checks out of the immediate area where actual work is happening, removing a bit of noise from the areas which raise these methods .

Answer (score 1):

Using an isolation framework for unit testing would make things much easier.

You could use for example the Microsoft Fakes Framework for writing custom stub implementations of interfaces and abstract classes.

It is even possible to intercept and detour any .NET Code and other dependencies (e.g. SharePoint, Third-Party Assemblies etc.).

The following block post contains some example that demonstrates the use of a DispatcherTimer fake:

http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/04/25/visual-studio-11-fakes-part-2/

Comment: Consider adding an example of raising a static event on a class with one of those frameworks.

Comment: The following block post contains some example that demonstrates the use of a DispatcherTimer fake: http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/04/25/visual-studio-11-fakes-part-2/

Comment: Edit the original answer with this link so I can upvote it please :)